# If local storage value goes below another value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use localStorage to tell me when a value is low. For example: if the localStorage value is below 5, say you are low on so and so. I have made a localStorage variable called "item1" (the number available) and another called "stockr1" (which is what the item1 has to go below) and finally one called "stockm1" (the message to display in the div when item1 goes below stockr1 (if item1 <= stockr1 then display stockm1).

Here is the code (the localStorage references are set on another page)

```
    <center>
          <body bgcolor="#FFD801"             
       onload="document.body.style.opacity='1';myFunction(); ">
   <div align="center">
       <p id="show" ></p>
   <script>
      function myFunction() {
   if(parseInt(localStorage.item1, 10) <= parseInt(localStorage.stokr1, 10))
     {
    document.getElementById('show').innerHtml = localStorage.stockm1;

 // if you use jquery
//$('#controlinwhichyouwanttoshowmessge').html(stockm1);
     } 
      }
       </script>

    </div>
        </body>
</center>
    </font>
     </html>
```

Comment: Are variables `item1`, `stockm1` and `stockr1` arrays or normal variables?

Comment: Also I will suggest you to see other questions of how they give information about code. Your question does not include any code.

Comment: Local storage doesn't do anything by itself, it just stores key/value pairs. You need to write a program to retrieve the values from local storage, then do the comparison, and display the results however you want. Where are you getting stuck? Do you not know how to retrieve the values from local storage? Do you not know how to write the comparison logic? Do you not know how to display the results?

Answer (score 0):

However your question does not provide all the information but I tried to give you an idea of what you should do based on what data you provided

```
if(parseInt(item1, 10) <= parseInt(stokr1, 10))
{
    document.getElementById('element_id_to_show_message').innerHtml = stockm1;

     // if you use jquery
    //$('#controlinwhichyouwanttoshowmessge').html(stockm1);
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but i cant seem to get the code to work, i dont know much JS

Comment: `parseInt` should never be used without specifying the radix.

Comment: @IngoBürk - Corrected

Comment: @torazaburo - Corrected

Comment: The answer you posted is nothing different then my code except for your parseInt fuction doesn't have radix argument passed. Also you calculated `n` but you didn't use it `var n = a <= b;`

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i did thid:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Reminders</title>
     </head>
            <font face="monospace" size="6" color="#3a3a3a">


            <center>
        <body bgcolor="#FFD801" onload="document.body.style.opacity='1';myFunction(); ">
           <div align="center">
               <p id="demo" ></p>
        <script>
             function myFunction() {
         var a = parseInt(localStorage.item1) ;
         var b = parseInt(localStorage.stockr1) ;



     var n = a <= b;
               if (a <= b){

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =   localStorage.stockm1;
                  }
        }
            </script>

         </div>
             </body>
      </center>
         </font>
        </html>
```